# Align barplot with boxplot in R

Tags: r, plot, alignment, bar-chart, boxplot

I would like to plot a distribution of counts using the barplot function in R, and underlay it with a boxplot to include information on median, quartiles, and outliers. A not-too-elegant solution for this has been found for histogram and boxplots: http://rgraphgallery.blogspot.com/2013/04/rg-plotting-boxplot-and-histogram.html.

There are many places online where one can find the argument being made that numerical data should be plotted with histograms while categorical data should be plotted with bar plots. My data are numerical, and in fact on a ratio scale (as they are counts), but because they are *discrete*, I want columns with gaps, not columns that touch, which seems to be the only option for histogram().

I currently have the following, but bar- and boxplot do not align quite perfectly:

```
set.seed(476372)
counts1 <- rpois(10000,3)
nf <- layout(mat = matrix(c(1,2),2,1, byrow=TRUE),  height = c(3,1))
par(mar=c(3.1, 3.1, 1.1, 2.1))
barplot(prop.table(table(counts1)))
boxplot(counts1, horizontal=TRUE,  outline=TRUE,ylim=c(0,12), frame=F, width = 10)
```

Here my question: How can I make them align?

Comment: if one of the answers meets your needs, can you please accept it? It provides closure within SO (and, whether or not it's my answer), is a pat-on-the-back to the answerer.

Answer (score 5):

Another option that's similar but a little more work. This preserves the option for gaps between the bars:

```
tbl <- prop.table(table(counts1))
left <- -0.4 + do.call('seq', as.list(range(counts1)))
right <- left + (2 * 0.4)
bottom <- rep(0, length(left))
top <- tbl
xlim <- c(-0.5, 0.5) + range(counts1)

nf <- layout(mat = matrix(c(1,2),2,1, byrow=TRUE),  height = c(3,1))
par(mar=c(3.1, 3.1, 1.1, 2.1))
plot(NA, xlim=xlim, ylim=c(0, max(tbl)))
rect(left, bottom, right, top, col='gray')
boxplot(counts1, horizontal=TRUE,  outline=TRUE, ylim=xlim, frame=F, width = 10)
```

[image]

Comment: Hello @r2evans, thanks, that looks great. Did not know the rect() function yet, so this is definitely a very useful knowledge gain. 
So the aligning works here because plot() and boxplot() have the same way of aligning things?

Comment: It aligns because we calculate `xlim` to be what we think it should be and force `plot` and `boxplot` to use it. `rect` is a bit of a lower-level function; if you are going to do this often, it would not be difficult to make a `hist`-like function that takes many/most of the same arguments as `hist` and adds on `gap` or something similar.

Comment: Yeah, I saw you setting `ylim=xlim`. However, if I do the following:

`limits <- c(-0.5,0.5) + range(counts1)
barplot(prop.table(table(counts1)),xlim=limits)
boxplot(counts1, horizontal=TRUE,  outline=TRUE,ylim=limits, frame=F, width = 10)`

the graphs still do not line up, which prompted my thought that barplot and boxplot use some different type of graphical parameter.

Comment: If you look at the return value from `barplot`, you'll see (and the help discusses) that it tells you where the center of each bar is along the x axis. I haven't tried to grok the whole `barplot.default` function yet, but I can't imagine why the midpoints are chosen as they are. Since there isn't a way to coerce `barplot` to use different logic, that's why I had to use `plot` and `rect` manually.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe using a "fake" histogram at the end

```
ht=hist(counts1,breaks=12,plot = F)
ht$counts=as.numeric(table(counts1))
ht$density=as.numeric(prop.table(table(counts1)))
ht$breaks=as.numeric(names(table(counts1)))
ht$mids=sapply(1:(length(ht$breaks)-1),function(z)mean(ht$breaks[z:(z+1)]))

plot(ht,freq=F,col=3,main="")
boxplot(counts1, horizontal=TRUE,outline=TRUE,ylim=range(ht$breaks), frame=F, col="green1", width = 10)
```

[image]

Comment: Hello @Robert, taking all the options for hist() apart if definitely instructional, thank you! However, the issue with the gaps remains....