# How do I get x-axis labels to show in R Barplot?

Tags: r

Probably pretty simple but I am a newb to R (and to stack)...

Can't seem to get the car names to show on the x-axis of my barplot.

I tried pasting in the example given in the "How to display all x labels in R barplot?" Question but that didn't work

My code is below. Does that code work for anybody else?

```
#plot of efficiency of 4 cylinder cars
#get 4cylinder cars seperate
fourcyl <- subset(mtcars, cyl == "4")
#barplot in descending order... need to add in car names.
barplot(fourcyl$mpg[order(fourcyl$mpg, decreasing = TRUE)], 
        horiz=FALSE,
        ylab = "Miles per Gallon",
        main = "Efficiency for 4 cylinder vehicles",
        ylim = c(0,35))
```

Comment: I copied the code he supplied but even that boxplot didn't have any x-axis labels when I ran it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Pascal's comment links to two possible solutions, but the bottom line is that you need to add the car names manually.

To know *which* car names to use takes a first step: if you look at `mtcars`, you'll see that they don't appear under a column header, meaning they are the row names. To get at them, simply:

```
carnames <- rownames(fourcyl)[ order(fourcyl$mpg, decreasing=TRUE) ]
```

From here, you need to know *how* and *where* to add them. Perhaps the first place many people look is to `axis`, where you'd do something like:

```
axis(side=1, at=1:length(carnames), labels=carnames)
```

But you'd be disappointed on at least two accounts: first, you don't see all of the names, since `axis` courteously ensures they don't overlap by omitting some; second, the ones that do show are not aligned properly under the corresponding vertical bar.

To fix the first, you can try rotating the text. You could use `las` (see `help(par)`) and do something like:

```
axis(side=1, at=1:length(carnames), labels=carnames, las=2)
```

But again you'll be a little disappointed in that many of the names will run over the default bottom margin (and disappear). You can fix with this a preceding `par(mar=...)` (again, see the help there and play with it some to find the right parameters), but there are solutions that provide slightly better methods (aesthetically), two of which are mentioned in @Pascal's link (really, go there).

The other problem -- *where* to put the labels -- is resolved by reading `help(barplot)` and noticing that the return value from `barplot(...)` is a matrix providing the mid-point of each of the bars. Odd, perhaps, but it is what it is (and it has a good reason, somewhere). So, capture this and you'll be nearly home-free:

```
bp <- barplot(fourcyl$mpg[order(fourcyl$mpg, decreasing = TRUE)], 
              horiz=FALSE, ylab = "Miles per Gallon",
              main = "Efficiency for 4 cylinder vehicles",
              ylim = c(0,35))
```

Now, to copy one of the link's suggestions, try:

```
text(x=bp[,1], y=-1, adj=c(1, 1), carnames, cex=0.8, srt=45, xpd=TRUE)
```

(No need for the `axis` command, just `bp <- barplot(...)`, `carnames <- ...`, and `text(...)`.)

Comment: Many thanks for your thorough answer. It worked. Was struggling with that for most of the day. Your response is most appreciated.

Comment: Sometimes people prefer to have more control than `barplot` provides, so they need to revert to making the bars manually. I suggested (with more features) an answer to a different question here at [SO #30794373](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30793211/align-barplot-with-boxplot-in-r/30794373#30794373) using `plot` and `rect`, if you're curious.