# how can I plot the bar plot attached to box plot

Tags: r, plot, bar-chart, boxplot

a small portion of my data looks like below

```
dt<- structure(c(79L, 54L, 37L, 41L, 42L, 121L, 134L, 169L, 23L, 19L, 
22L, 19L, 25L), .Names = c("Experi_1", "Experi_2", "Experi_3", 
"Experi_4", "Experi_5", "Experi_6", "Experi_7", "Experi_8", "Experi_9", 
"Experi_10", "Experi_11", "Experi_12", "Experi_13"))
```

What I try to make is to make a barplot assigned to a box plot under 
I have read this comment already and I tried to use it but with no success

[Align barplot with boxplot in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30793211/align-barplot-with-boxplot-in-r?noredirect=1&lq=1)

A bar plot can simply be drawn like this. however, I have no control over my x-axis. for example if I want to plot it with a distance of 5, I cannot. lets say 1, 5, 10 and 13 as the x-axis label. Anyway this is not a big issue. the problem is with assigning a box plot to this barplot!

```
barplot(dt, xlab="Number of S in each experiment")
```

I used the following to add the box plot, but it does not seem to do it

```
xlim <- c(-0.5, 0.5) + range(dt)
par(mar=c(3.1, 3.1, 1.1, 2.1))
boxplot(dt, horizontal=TRUE,  outline=TRUE, ylim=xlim, frame=F, width = 10)
```

Comment: Can you clarify what are you trying to show in the barplot? Are you sure you don't want a histogram rather than a barplot?

Comment: @jkt Thanks for your message. I am sure I don't want a histogram. But even with histogram, I still cannot add this box plot to it. I am trying to show how many signals I have identified in each experiment. so I don't need to do the frequency but the values

Comment: @jkt I removed the main from the barplot to avoid misunderstanding

Comment: @C8H10N4O2 does it matter ? both are the same. if I align a box plot or assign a box plot to a plot, I think both give the same idea, no? please correct me if I am mistaken

Comment: @nik no it doesn't.  if I assign a box plot to another plot, I get one plot.  If I align a box plot with another plot, then I get two plots, side by side.

Comment: @C8H10N4O2 oh OK thanks, then I assign a box plot to another. I want only one plot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is that you don't split your window. Use `layout()` to do this (as suggested by the post).

```
layout(mat = matrix(c(1,2),2,1, byrow=TRUE),  height = c(3,1))
par(mar=c(3.1, 3.1, 1.1, 2.1))
barplot(dt, main="Distribution", xlab="Number of each experiment")
boxplot(dt, horizontal=TRUE,  outline=TRUE, frame=F, width = 10)
```

Comment: I already liked your answer; i have two questions, one is how to adjust the x-axis label ? for example if I only want to show Experi1, Experi7 and experi 13, then how to do that ? second is that what can I understand from this box plot? does this take into account the entire data? for example what is the median? do you know ?

Comment: @nik The median is the value that divides the upper half from the lower half of your data. The boxplot takes into account the entire data and plots outliers as separate points outside the whiskers. Remove the `ylim` argument from `boxplot` to see your outlier(s).[re x-labels: pls see my answer to your separate query].

Comment: @nik Your comment made me realise that it's clearer if I remove `ylim`. I initially understood that you wanted to align axes, but that doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: if you remove the ylim then you don't have both plots in one plot.

Comment: @nik ?? This is not true. `ylim` has no impact on `layout`. Try again.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to use the 'layout' line.
The following should work.

```
    nf <- layout(mat = matrix(c(1,2),2,1, byrow=TRUE),  height = c(3,1))
    par(mar=c(3.1, 3.1, 1.1, 2.1))
    barplot(dt, main="Distribution", xlab="Number of each experiment")
    boxplot(dt, horizontal=TRUE,  outline=TRUE, ylim=xlim, frame=F, width = 10)
```

Comment: a similar answer is given above! so to make sure I accept the right answer, i have two questions, one is how to adjust the x-axis label ? for example if I only want to show Experi1, Experi7 and experi 13, then how to do that ? second is that what can I understand from this box plot? does this take into account the entire data? for example what is the median? do you know ?